# what is the solution to $\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I saw on my notebook that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and there's this step:
$\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-x)} = \frac{1}{1-x} - (x^n - x^n) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ but I can't understand why.

Here are all the steps:

$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} = $

$ =\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x} =$

$=\frac{1}{1-x} - x^{n+1}(1-x)^-1 =$

$=\frac{1}{1-x} - (x^n - x^n)=$

$=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Hi welcome to Math.SE! It might be a good idea to learn MathJax formatting http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to make your question more readable. You should look up the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series, which can be proven by induction.

Comment: There may be something missing in your notes. First of all, of course, we must say that $|x|<1,$ otherwise the thing you're trying to prove isn't true at all. And then you have a sequence of equations, most of which are true, but one of them is only really an _approximate_ equality, and only for large values of $n$. Moreover, it makes no sense to write it that way. You might want to try to get access to a better set of notes or try to find this in your textbook, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the nth partial sum

$S_n = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^n$.

Now consider $xS_n = x \sum_{i=0}^n x^i = x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^n + x^{n+1}$.

Then subtracting and factoring, we have $S_n - xS_n = S_n (1-x) = (1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^n)- (x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^n + x^{n+1}) = 1 - x^{n+1}$.

Then $S_n = \frac{1-{x^{n+1}}}{1-x}$.

What you have, the sum evaluating to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is only true if $|x| \lt 1$.

To see this, let $n \to \infty$ in our expression for $S_n$. Then since $|x| \lt 1$, $x^{n+1} \to 0$. Thus the sum comes to $\frac{1 - 0}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ but only when $x<1$.

Proof: It is well known that sum of n terms of a geometric progression {$a,ax,ax^2.....$} is given by $a(1-x^n)/(1-x)$.

Now in your situation, $a=1$. And as I mentioned this case is only $x<1$. So, as n becomes infinitely large, $x^n$ becomes very small or reaches to $0$. and ultimately the summation formula becomes  $\frac{a(1-x^n)}{(1-x)}=\frac{1(1-0)}{1-x}=1/1-x$